# How to setup a domain to HTML ahrefs

Tags: html

Let’s say I bought a domain (example.com). How do I implement example.com on ahrefs (in HTML) so I can forward a page to a hyperlink like (example.com/about)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/about">About Page</a>
```